# couch db synchronous call using jQuery couch api

Tags: jquery, couchdb

I am using jquery couch api.

while calling jquery couch api method like openDoc or while calling view,
i want to call them synchronously

so if i write three different view one by one, they must be execute one after another. how can i make such behavior with jquery.cocuh.js

Please give some example.

Thanks
Nirmal

Answer (score 0):

You can make direct jQuery.ajax sync calls one by one. Syntax is like

```
$.ajax({
  url:'https://some.url/dbname/_design/ddoc/_view/view',
  method:'GET',
  async: false,
  data:{
    startkey:JSON.stringify('...'), 
    endkey:JSON.stringify('...'), 
    limit: 100
  },
  success: function(response){ /* do something */}
});
```

Although sync approach is sub-optimal, cause it freeze UI. Using chain of promises looks more sensible.

```
$.ajax({/* Request #1 opts */})
.then(function(response1){
  return $.ajax({ /* Request #2 opts */ })
})
.then(function(response2){
  return $.ajax({ /* Request #3 opts */ })
})
.then(function(response3){
  // do something here
})
.fail(function(reason){
  // handle error
});
```